# C++ Need help sorting a 2D string array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm a little stuck with sorting a string `Table[X][Y]`. As tagged, Im using C++ and have to use standard libraries and make it for all C++ (not only C++ 11).

The size of the `Table` is fixed (i get the X reading how many lines a file has and the Y is fixed because thats the different "attributes" has each line).

When i create the Table, each part of it is obtained as `Table[X][Y] = stringX.data();` from things previously read from a file and stored in strings. I have numbers in the first column (the one im going to use as sorting criteria), names, address, etc in the others.

The part where the Table is created is:

```
Table[i][0] = string1.data();
Table[i][1] = string2.data();
Table[i][2] = string3.data();
Table[i][3] = string4.data();
Table[i][4] = string5.data();
```

Where "i" is the current "iteration" of a `while(fgets)` that reads one line at a time from a file, does some operations and stores in those strings the "final values" of each part of the line read.

I have to sort that Table using the first column as criteria in decreasing order.

Lets imagine the Table is like this: `Table[4][3]`

```
20 | Jhon  | 14th July 
2  | Mary  | 9th June
44 | Mark  | 10th December
1  | Chris | 4th Feb
```

And i need the output to be this:

```
44 | Mark  | 10th December
20 | Jhon  | 14th July 
2  | Mary  | 9th June
1  | Chris | 4th Feb
```

I have been reading several questions and pages and they sort int/chars arrays or convert the array into vector and then work with them. Im trying to sort the string Table i have without converting anything (dunno if possible).

I dont know if i managed to explain the issue and the situation i have clear enough. Im not putting all the code i have because apart from the declaration of the string Table and the strings that are then placed as string.data in the Table, the rest of the code has nothing to do with the Table and the sorting process. The code opens the file, reads line by line, filters the info i need from some separators and special characters and places each of the "rankings criteria" to a string, then assigns a "ranking" after evaluating each of the criterias and giving a total score (which then is stored in "string1").
After all this is done, i create the string `Table[x][y]` and place the filtered and processed information in that Table one row at a time (because i assing this while reading each line from the file).

The only thing that remains is the sorting of the table from the best scored to the last and then create a file with the top 10.

I appreciate and thank in advance the time you took reading this and any tip, information, code or source from where i can read this that you could provide.

Comment: *The size of the Table is fixed (i get the X reading how many lines a file has and the Y is fixed because thats the different "attributes" has each line).* -- That doesn't sound like a "fixed" size to me.  The size depends on the number of lines.  If that's the case, and `X` and `Y` are actually runtime variables, then `std::string Table[X][Y];` is not valid C++.  Instead of describing, post a [mcve].  It doesn't matter where the data comes from if the goal is to sort on the first column.

Comment: To be clear, you left out the most important information concerning your code -- how is `Table` actually declared?  Again, if it's something like `int X; int Y; X = somevalue; Y = somevalue;...std::string Table[X][Y];`, then that is not standard C++, thus your goal of making this C++ is not going to be fulfilled.

Comment: I get the X from this code:

while(fgets(inputArray, sizeof(inputArray), fp) != NULL)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }

With this i read all the file and get all the lines the file has, then i use the variable "lineCount" as X in the Table.

The Y is the number of "attributes" each person has. In my case is 6 (name, lastname, birth, gender, address) and the last one is the value i give each of them

And Table is declared just as i've said => string Table[lineCount][6]

Comment: Well as stated, that is not valid C++.   Variable length arrays have never been part of standard C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by compile-time constants, not runtime variables.  If the number of columns is fixed, then a `std::vector<std::array<std::string, 6>> Table(lineCount);` would be valid C++.  A variable length array in C++ is `std::vector`.  What you're using now is a compiler extension offered by some compiles, but if you're curious, your code would fail to compile using Visual Studio or some other compiler that does not accept the non-standard syntax.

Comment: don't call data() to store the string char data. just store the string itself.

Comment: lineCount is an int declare and initialized as 0 in the main => int lineCount=0; .
Then after the while ends and has read all the lines in the file, i get the total number of lines. That int is then passed on the string Table as the X, and the Y is fixed at 6.
After i have placed all the info i want in each part of the string Table using the code i've provided before (the "Table[i][0]=string1.data();" that is inside a while), i have the final string Table. The source file i'm using now to test the code has 10 lines, so i end up with a string Table[10][6].

Comment: I' using Dev-C++ as a compiler... i was not aware that the code i wrote wasn't standard C++

Comment: I have removed the .data(); part from the Table[x][y] = string part. I dont know why earlier today i had to put .data() there or i would get a compile error. Maybe i was writing something wrong somewhere that made that error.

Comment: @lDemutl -- Dev-C++ is not a compiler it is an IDE.  The actual compiler that is being used is g++, and maybe a very old version.  Second, g++, by default allows this syntax -- if you were to use `-Wall -pedantic` as the compile options, you will see that the code doesn't compile.  Third, *if* you were to use proper C++ using `std::vector` and `std::array`, then sorting on the first column is very simple using `std::sort` and the proper predicate.  Last is that how you populate that 2D array is not important and really isn't necessary to see the technique of sorting on the first column.

Comment: Aside: Rather than having a `std::string [3]` as your data type, you would do well to have something like `struct datum { int ranking; std::string name; std::chrono::month_day birthday; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned in the comments, a variable length array is accomplished in C++ by using `std::vector`.  The current syntax you're using

`std::string Table[X][Y]`

where either `X` or `Y` are runtime variables, is not legal C++.  Given your example, a standard C++ declaration would be this:

`std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>> Table;`

So let's assume that this is what you are going to use.

---

The next step is to sort the data based on the first column.  That can be accomplished by utilizing the [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)  algorithm function, along with the appropriate predicate indicating that you are using the first column as the sorting criteria.

Here is a short example, using your data, of how this is all accomplished:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>> Table;

    // Set up the test data  
    Table.push_back({"20", "Jhon", "14th July"});
    Table.push_back({"2", "Mary", "9th June"});
    Table.push_back({"44", "Mark", "10th December"});
    Table.push_back({"1", "Chris", "4th Feb"});

    std::cout << "Before sort:\n\n";
    for (auto& s : Table)
        std::cout << s[0] << " | " << s[1] << " | " << s[2] << "\n";
        
    std::cout << "\n\nAfter sort:\n\n";
    
    // Sort the data using the first column of each `std::array` as the criteria
    std::sort(Table.begin(), Table.end(), [&](auto& a1, auto& a2) 
              { return std::stoi(a1[0]) > std::stoi(a2[0]); });

    // Output the results: 
    for (auto& s : Table)
        std::cout << s[0] << " | " << s[1] << " | " << s[2] << "\n";
}
```

Here is the final output:

```
Before sort:

20 | Jhon | 14th July
2 | Mary | 9th June
44 | Mark | 10th December
1 | Chris | 4th Feb


After sort:

44 | Mark | 10th December
20 | Jhon | 14th July
2 | Mary | 9th June
1 | Chris | 4th Feb
```

The output needs a little bit of formatting, but that's not important.

Remember, it is *not* important as to where the data comes from, whether it is from a file or hardcoded as the example above shows.  However you populate the `Table`, that's up to you. The goal is to show you once populated, how to sort the data.

---

The first thing we did was create the Table and fill it in with the test data.  Note that the vector has a `push_back` function to add entries to the vector.

Then the call to `std::sort` has a predicate function (the lambda), where the predicate is given two items, in this case it would be two `std::array`'s by reference.  Then the goal is to return if the first `std::array` (in this case, `a1`) should be placed before the second `std::array` (`a2`).

Note that we only care about the first column, so we only need to consider array[0] of each of those arrays, and compare them.

Also note that since array[0] is a `std::string`, we simply can't compare it lexicographically -- we need to convert the string to an `int` and compare the `int` value.  That's the reason for the `std::stoi` call to convert to an integer.

The final thing about the sort predicate is that we want to have a descending sort.  Thus the comparing operator to use is `>` instead of the "traditional" `<` (which would have sorted in a ascending manner).

Hopefully this explains what the code is doing.

---

Edit:

Since you are attempting to get this code to work in C++98, the easiest way to do that is

1. Change to `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` instead of `std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>>`
2. Not use the brace-initialization that C++11 offers
3. Use a comparison function instead of a lambda.

Given that, here is the code for C++98:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool SortFirstColumn(const std::vector<std::string>& a1,
                     const std::vector<std::string>& a2)
{
   return atoi(a1[0].c_str()) > atoi(a2[0].c_str());
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> Table;

    // Set up the test data  
    std::vector<std::string> vect(3);
    vect[0] = "20"; 
    vect[1] = "Jhon"; 
    vect[2] = "14th July"; 
    Table.push_back(vect);
    vect[0] = "2"; 
    vect[1] = "Mary"; 
    vect[2] = "9th June"; 
    Table.push_back(vect);
    vect[0] = "44"; 
    vect[1] = "Mark"; 
    vect[2] = "10th December"; 
    Table.push_back(vect);
    vect[0] = "1"; 
    vect[1] = "Chris"; 
    vect[2] = "10th December"; 
    Table.push_back(vect);

    std::cout << "Before sort:\n\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Table.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << Table[i][0] << " | " << Table[i][1] << " | " << Table[i][2] << "\n";
        
    std::cout << "\n\nAfter sort:\n\n";
    
    // Sort the data using the first column of each `std::vector<std::string>` as the criteria
    std::sort(Table.begin(), Table.end(), SortFirstColumn);

    // Output the results: 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Table.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << Table[i][0] << " | " << Table[i][1] << " | " << Table[i][2] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: When i try this code in the online compiler "cpp.sh" with the options C++98 and warnings -Wpedantic i get the following error: "#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options" (apart from different errors generated by using push back, for example). When using C++11 it fails because lambda parameter is only for C++14. When using C++14 it runs without issue, but since i have to use C++98 (to make it usable in any compiler) i have this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to make this sort C++98 possible? I get what this code is doing and it's really helpfull to allow me to understand the sorting, but since i can't use push back in C98 i'm a little lost as to how to approach this issue.  Nonetheless, i'm really gratefull for the time and the answer, it will help me understand a lot more vectors and sorting.

Comment: Im getting "cannot convert 'const std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)' in line 9, when return atoi is located.  Now im looking at the code and trying to understands what that line is trying to do and how to solve it. I kknow that atoi converts string to int and that c_str gives a char pointer of a string, but i would need to understand the whole line.

Comment: The closing parentheses were placed wrong.  Now the code should compile.

Comment: Great, just tested and working ok. Now i'll change the vector initialization from this defined structure to a loop where i place each component from a string. This strings are filled with the info read line by line from the file and tokenized because they have "&" that separates each field. The columns are 6 so it should be "vect(6)".
I think i can manage to adapt it with no further problems... but if i happen to find issues, i may bother you another time (if its ok with you). Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've eddited the question. I've tried modifying your code to addapt it to get the values of the vector from strings attained by reading the file and i get an error. Clearly im doing something wrong, but i can't find out what

Comment: I suggest you open a new question, where the only concern is the reading (the sorting has been taken care of with the answer).

Comment: Found the error... i was writing Table.push.back instead of Table.push_back